# Not able to run exisitng angular project - Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular-cli

I am not able to run an existing project and getting an error "Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found."
my package.config having these values(not a complete file)

```
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8888",
    "test": "karma start karma.webpack.conf.js",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --bail",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.4",
 }
```

and when I run outside project folder this is what I got

> ng version

```
"Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 12.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.4
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.4
@schematics/angular          0.8.4
@schematics/update           0.8.4
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2"
```

and when I run inside src project folder this is what I got

> ng version

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 12.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    <error>
@angular-devkit/core         <error>
@angular-devkit/schematics   <error>
@schematics/angular          <error>
@schematics/update           <error>
rxjs                         6.2.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run into this issue, it’s probably because your global **`@angular/cli`** , project **`@angular/cli`** version or **`@angular/compiler-cli`** doesn’t match.

First of all run

```
ng -v
```

to check the global version **(i.e it outputs 5.2.0)** and then look into your project **`package.json`**, if it match with the project versions.

```
"@angular/cli": "6.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
```

**Fix it**

If something doesn’t match, update or downgrade it. For example to downgrade project **`@angular/cli`** run

```
npm uninstall -D @angular/cli
npm install -D @angular/cli@5.2.0
```

To upgrade global run **`@angular/cli`** run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

> Note

It is necessary to have both a global and local install for the tools to work.

In global mode (**-g** or **–global** appended to the command), it uninstalls/installs the package as a global package. To uninstall/install the project package use **-D** or **–save-dev** and package will be removed/added to your devDependencies.

The @ after package name specifies the desired version.

---

## **Second Option**

And For Me i solved the problem by following the following steps

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli --no-optional`
4. `ng new new-project`
5. `ng s / ng s -o`

---

## **Third Option**

If you run the command 'ng new my-app' when you are already in the app folder it opens yet another folder with the same name inside. Check whether you run the command 'ng serve' in the first or second folder.

Example:

If you run '`ng serve`' in: **C:\Users\hoehmann\my-app**

you need to run it in: **C:\Users\hoehmann\my-app\my-app**

Comment: in package.json  inside "devDependencies": {    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.4", }while global version is Angular CLI: 6.2.4, do i need to try option 1?

Comment: my complier cli is @angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0 but when i run  npm install -D @angular/cli@4.0.0 i am getting error "No matching version found for @angular/cli@4.0.0."

Comment: don't use @ and after version just use `npm install @angular/cli` or `npm i @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208623/discussion-between-f11-and-kiran-mistry).